# UIButton Background Images appear lighter in Simulator than in IB

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, interface, interface-builder

Just put a background image on a button.  The looks fine in IB but when I build and run the project in Simulator the bg is noticeably lighter.  Anyone know why could be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the case that the alpha value for your view or one of its superviews in less than 100% (value 1.0).  I've seen cases where a superview had low alpha, but the subviews appeared solid in Interface Builder, while of course they were transparent or translucent when I actually ran the app.